# How to search for a negated Unicode backreference (PCRE)?

Tags: regex, unicode, pcre, backreference

I'd like to find two non-identical Unicode words separated by a colon using a PCRE regex.

Take for example, this string:

**Lôrem:ipsüm dõlör:sït amêt:amêt cønsectetûr:cønsectetûr âdipiscing:elït**

I can easily find the two identical words separated by a colon using:

(\p{L}+):(\1)

which will match: **cønsectetûr:cønsectetûr** and **amêt:amêt**

However, I want to negate the backreference to find only non-identical Unicode words separated by a colon.

What's the proper way to negate a backreference in PCRE?

(\p{L}+):(**^**\1) obviously does **not** work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by using a negative lookahead to prevent a match if the captured part repeats after the colon:

```
(\p{L}+):(?!\1)
```

Then you need to match the second unicode word, another `\p{L}+`:

```
(\p{L}+):(?!\1)\p{L}+
```

And last, to prevent false matches, use word boundaries:

```
\b(\p{L}+):(?!\1\b)\p{L}+\b
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lB0hA7)

Comment: You can remove the last word boundary.